# writing scraped data to csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping out the 'h2' and 'h3' tags from some html pages and want to write them to a csv file under particular columns. How to create columns and then insert rows under them using python scrapy.

My code is:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    f = open("fquestdata.csv","wb")
    for site in sites:
         quest = site.select('//h2').extract()
         ans = site.select('//h3').extract()
         f.write(ans)
```

but it gives an error that says:

exceptions.TypeError: must be string or buffer, not list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting more then one answer. Try

```
for s in ans:
  f.write(s)
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks a lot robert
but now the error is:

exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)

Can you please help me with this too.

Comment: try smart_str http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character/

Comment: but how to create columns in a csv file and insert rown under them

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use custom Csv item exporter ?  [suggested reading](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html)

or

write your own code  [suggested reading](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)